# JavaScript For-Loop Question: Why Am I getting a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am working through Javascript for Kids, which is a surprisingly fun little book for a beginner, but I'm having trouble testing a For Loop example in the text:

```js
var sheepCounted = 0;
for (var sheepCounted = 0; sheepCounted < 10; sheepCounted++) {
  console.log(“I have counted” + sheepCounted + “sheep!”);
}
console.log(sheepCounted);
```

When I use a Javascript tester to test this example I get a syntax error, but I'm not sure why? Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: you have incorrect characters `”` this is not same as `"`.did you copy the code from pdf file ?

Comment: What is the exact error message and line?

Comment: Oh please, 2 upvotes for a syntax error related question? You've got to be kidding me

Comment: Remove the "var" within the "for", as you have already declared the variable in the previous line

Comment: What's wrong with the upvotes @AlonEitan? The question is well written, shows the relevant code, has the proper tags and title.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto This is an old question, but since you asked - The upvote button titled as _"This question shows **research effort**; it is **useful** and clear"_, I don't think that there's anything useful about this question, and it's definitely doesn't shows any research. Just a simple and obvious bug that the OP could have avoided if he was using a proper IDE or just by following the basic syntax of JS

Comment: Nice of you to explain in detail. I think this might happens to other ppl and that it's a useful addition to the SO repertory, that's why I upvoted. But I get your point, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line which uses `“ ”`:

```
console.log(“I have counted” + sheepCounted + “sheep!”);
```

To this with `" "`:

```
console.log("I have counted" + sheepCounted + "sheep!");
```